# Python Performance: While vs For Loops

Tags: python

Someone told me that *while* loops are usually faster than *for* loops.

Is that even true? And if yes, why is that?

Comment: It depends on *which* `while` loop you want to compare with *which* `for` loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's give it a try:

```
def f():
    for i in range(100000):
        ...

def g():
    i = 0
    while i < 100000:
        i += 1

>>> %timeit f()
2.29 ms ± 69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit g()
5.77 ms ± 26.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Busted. But, seriously, none of such comparison will make much sense for the following reasons:

1. While you can implement any `for`-loop as a `while`-loop, that new loop will have extra code to match the functionality
2. `while` and `for` serve different purposes and comparing them is like comparing apples with oranges
3. It's Python, nobody really cares about nanoseconds here.
4. A choice between `for` and `while` is *highly unlikely* to become a performance bottleneck.